# Multiple form and switching them

Tags: javascript, html

Hi dears i want to know how to switch among forms within one page in html using jquery script php or other 
But i use it like below:

```
<div id="div">
         <button href="#" id="1" onclick="func()">         </button>
         <button href="#" id="2" onclick="func()">         </button>
         <button href="#" id="3" onclick="func()">         </button>
</div>


<div id="f1" style="display: none">
    <form id="a" >

    </form>
</div>

<div id="f2" style="display: none">
    <form id="b">

    </form>

</div>

<div id="f3" style="display: none">
    <form id="c">

    </form>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function func() {

           if (document.getElementById("1").onclick){
               document.getElementById("f1").style.display = "block";
           }

             if (document.getElementById("2").onclick){
            document.getElementById("f2").style.display = "block";
           }

           if(document.getElementById("3").onclick){
            document.getElementById("f3").style.display = "block";
          }

    }
</script>
```

1. first i want to use switch case instead of if if else
2. I want to have multiple forms more than 3 but i have to block or hide many times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need only one line of js code. Just pass `this` to your func like:

```
<button href="#" id="1" onclick="func(this)">         </button>
```

And then in your script:

```
function func(elem) {
    var forms = document.getElementsByTagName('form');
    for(var i=0;i<forms.length;i++){
        forms[i].parentNode.style.display = 'none';
    }
    document.getElementById("f"+elem.id).style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: Thank you :)
But it only does  once
I have to refresh browser everytime i want to choose one of those three button

Comment: @MahdiShahpuri do you want only one form visible?

Comment: Yes.       

                 I want to have one form visible. It only works correct once and i have to refresh the browser for each button